# SOQL: Finding Related Cases

Tags: soql, case

How do you find `related Cases` in a given `Case`
I have `Related Order` & `Related Event`, I need a way to find our how many Related Order`are assigned to each`Related Event`

Here is what I have done so far:

```
map<ID,Case> toMap = new map<ID,Case>();
List<Case> releatedCases = [SELECT parentId,id FROM Case where recordtype.name = 'Related Order'];

for(Case relatedOrderCase : releatedCases) 
{
  toMap.put(relatedOrderCase.parentId, relatedOrderCase);  
}

system.debug('related order: ' + releatedCases.size());
```

Related Event:

```
List<Case> releatedEventCases = [SELECT parentId,id FROM Case where recordtype.name = 'Related Event'];
```

//.....How to extract: how many Releated Order are assigned to each Releated Event?

Comment: So you're looking for related cases that have either of the two record types? Or are you looking for related cases where the two record types intersect, i.e. they share the same parentId? If the latter, I'd think you could do an aggregrate query with a count and group by or order by clause.

Comment: I'm looking for Related Order are assigned to each Related Event, other words, Related Event can have more than one Related Order so something like this: for an example: id:000000000 related event has 2 related order

Comment: Is related order the parentId?

Comment: yes related order parentid

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You'll want to run aggregate result queries to get the count(Id) of case records related to the same ParentId. For convenience, you can use an OrderBy or a GroupBy clause if you wish, but that it isn't necessary.

To get counts, do something like this:

```
List<AggregrateResult>relatedOrderCases = [SELECT count(Id), parentId FROM Case WHERE recordtype.name = 'Related Order'];

List<AggregrateResult>relatedEventCases = [SELECT count(Id), parentId FROM Case WHERE recordtype.name = 'Related Event'];
```

If you put these into maps by parentId and count, you could easily check for matches/intersections with parentIds.

```
map<Id,integer>MapRelatedOrder2Cases = new map<Id,integer>();
for(AggregateResult relatedOrder : relatedOrderCases) 
{
  MapRelatedOrder2Cases.put(relatedOrder.parentId,RelatedOrder.expr0);  
}

map<Id,integer>MapRelatedOrder2Event = new map<Id,integer>();
for(AggregateResult relatedEvent : relatedEventCases) 
{
  MapRelatedEvent2Cases.put(relatedEvent.parentId,relatedEvent.expr0);  
}
```

Now you need to find out where they intersect/overlap. Let's do that using the keysets.

```
set<Id>Ordrs = new set<Id>();
set<Id>Evts = new set<Id>();
set<Id>Both = new set<Id>();

Ordrs = MapRelatedOrder2Cases.keyset():
Evts = MapRelatedEvent2Cases.keyset();

Boolean result1 = Both.addAll(Ordrs);
System.assertEquals(true, result1);

Boolean result2 = Both.retainAll(Evts);
//Retains only the elements in the original set named Both that are contained in set Evts.
System.assertEquals(true, result2);
```

You now have a keyset of the overlapping parentIds If you want to get the totals of the Related Order and Event Cases, you can sum the values from the two maps as you iterate on the resulting keyset while putting the results into a new map. It would look like this:

```
map<Id,integer>MapRelatedOrder2Both = new map<Id,integer>();
for(Id bth:Both){
{
   if(MapRelatedOrder2Cases.containskey(bth) && MapRelatedEvent2Cases.containskey(bth))
   {
      MapRelatedOrder2Both.put(bth, MapRelatedOrder2Cases.get(bth) + MapRelatedEvent2Cases.get(bth));
   }
}
```

You now have the total of Order and Event mapped by parentId.

Comment: i could not able to run complain about `expecting a left parentheses, found )` i do not see which parentheses is talking about

Comment: i could not able to go to the second one; i'm getting on first one

Comment: error: `only date aggregate functions are allowed as grouping expressions: count`

Comment: same error even after changing to count(id)

Comment: See edited answer above. Needed to use AggregateResult queries. Have added code to get your totals too. Apologies for the initial misdirection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now on the very first line, I'm getting this error: `Field must be grouped or aggregated: ParentId`

Comment: Then use a GroupBy parentId on it. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm. I don't have your data to be able to sort it out precisely for you.